# Getting RGB's pixel related coordinate in pointcloud (real world) with openni

Tags: kinect, openni, camera, world, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone knows how to discover the pointcloud "pixel"(x,y,z in real world) giving a pixel (v,u) from RGB camera?

I am using a feature descriptor (ORB) in RGB frame (/camera/rgb/image_color) its returns the u,v from the plannar image, I want a relation of this RGB pixel (feature) to get the real world coordinate in pointcloud topic (/camera/depth_registered/points).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103761/getting-rgb%27s-pixel-related-coordinate-in-pointcloud-(real-world)-with-openni/) by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that right if I search into pointcloud vector with this method?

I want the pointcloud index to rgb pixel h=240,w=320 (the center of rgb image).

void cloud_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud)

{
int pcl_index, rgb_h, rgb_w;
rgb_h = 240;
rgb_w = 320;
pcl_index = (h*480) + rgb_w; // result is 115520
pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ point_pcl;
pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud,point_pcl);
std::cout << "(x,y,z) = " << point_pcl.at(pcl_index) << std::endl;
}

will it return the point in the pointcloud for the center pixel of the rgb camera?

thank you,

---

Originally posted by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) with karma: 168 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-03-13**:
I think it should be pcl_index = ( (rgb_w*cloud.height) + rgb_h);

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-03-14**:
Better method is to use at() member function.